# Работа с огромными файлами 'Out of Memory' - Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Здравствуйте прошу помочь адаптировать свой скрипт вот так: [клац](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28279669/%27Out-of-Memory%27-for-LoadFromFile.html#a39608160)

Или помочь решить как то это другим образом , вот сам скрипт.

```
procedure TForm1.sButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
var SL: TStringList;
     i, j: integer;
begin
    if sMemo2.Text='' then
    begin
        ShowMessage('Заполните поле ниже!');
        exit;
    end
    else
        if not OpenDialog1.Execute then Exit;

   sMemo1.clear;

   SL:= TStringList.Create;
   SL.LoadFromFile(OpenDialog1.FileName);

   for i:= 0 to sMemo2.Lines.Count-1 do
       for j:= 0 to SL.Count - 1 do
           if (pos(smemo2.lines[i],  SL.Strings[j]) <> 0) then
                     sMemo1.Lines.Add(SL.Strings[j]);

   sLabel1.Caption := IntToStr(sMemo1.Lines.Count);
   sButton2.Enabled:=True;

   SL.Free;
end;
```

Comment: опишите задачу подробнее. Не то, как вы ее пытаетесь решить, а саму задачу. И почему для хранения больших массивов данных вы используете файл, а не БД, например.

Comment: Использую файл так как по другому не умею. 
Работает так я в memo ввожу допустим 1 2 3 4 5 6 и открываю файл в memo2 выводит все совпадения где есть 1 2 3 4 5 6

Comment: и каков объем вашего файла?

Comment: 20гб примерно очень нужно помогите

Comment: и где то 30к запросов по этой базе

Comment: про то что делается в коде в целом я и так понял по коду. вопрос в том, откуда этот файл берется, и что в нем содержится и в каком формате. Работать с таким файлом не продуктивно, очевидно. 20 гигабайт текста это тоже просто дохренищи. Наиболее оптимальным путем будет использовать СУБД вместо файла. В любом случае загрузить его в память у вас не получится целиком. Читать последовательно при каждом поиске  - не эффективно и очень медленно.

Comment: Ну меня скорость где то в сутки устроит. Только как это сделать. Главное что бы работало

Comment: опять меня игнорируют кто то может помочь?

Answer (score 4):

Ошибка нехватки памяти резонно возникает при попытке загрузить в память файл размером в 20Гигабайт. Для решения задачи вы можете читать файл построчно. Для этого могут быть выбраны различные варианты, самым простым из которых является использование старых добрых функций `readln()`. У этого подхода, есть свои минусы в т.ч. в скорости работы, и если вы готовы использовать сторонние библиотеки для потокового чтения, то лучше подумать об их применении.
Вопрос о рассмотрении эффективности чтения больших файлов, в частности в старенькой `Delphi-7`, лучше вынести в отдельный вопрос.

В целом принцип останется неизменным, с помощью того или иного способа вы будете читать файл по строкам до конца, и затем искать в них совпадения. В своем коде у вас также внешний цикл поиска - это цикл по строкам Memo, что влечет за собой чтение файла N-раз, но поскольку вы вряд ли хотите читать 20Гб-файл несколько раз, то внешний цикл должен быть по файлу. А внутри уже поиск подстрок в каждой строке.

```
procedure TForm7.checkButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var f : TextFile;
    s : string;
    idx : integer;
    frBuffer : array[word] of char;
begin
    checkButton.Enabled := false;
    srcMemo.Enabled := false;

    AssignFile(f, 'D:\data.txt');
    reset(f);
    system.SetTextBuf(f, frBuffer); //буфер чтения 64кб

    try

        while not eof(f) do begin
            readln(f, s);

            for idx := 0 to srcMemo.Lines.Count - 1 do begin
               if (pos(srcMemo.Lines[idx], s) > 0) then begin
                   resultMemo.Lines.Add(s);
                   break;
               end;
            end;

            Application.ProcessMessages();
        end;

    finally
        CloseFile(f);

        srcMemo.Enabled := true;
        checkButton.Enabled := true;
    end;
end;
```

Отмечу, что при таком подходе при достаточно большом числе совпадений строк в файле вы все равно можете получить `OutOfMemory Exception`, переполнив `TMemo` с результатами совпадений.
Возможно, имеет смысл также увеличить буфер чтения для файла до больших  размеров, выделив память динамически.

Comment: всё бы ничего но я все ровно не знаю как это впихнуть в мой код :(